# Restlet GAE sample doesn't work with Google App Engine Toolkit 1.4.0

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I run GAE in Eclipse. What I did was just following instructions from sample: http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/275-restlet/252-restlet.pdf

When I try to access the URL localhost:8888/resttest I get an exception:

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.makeUnavailable(ServletHolder.java:415)
... the rest of stack trace
```

I tried with different versions of Restlets. Any idea how to get this working?

Yes, I use the GAE in Eclipse. web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
        <param-value>secretPackage.FirstTestApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Google Plugin for Eclipse? If not, I recommend you install the plugin as it simplifies the process somewhat.

Can you paste your web.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to add a jar: **org.restlet.ext.servlet.jar** as I did.